# Apply effect on microphone

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

i'm developing a browser voice communication app, so the problem is - i need to apply some effects on microphone input stream. i get the stream this way for the test where my interlocutor should hear a sine sound:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
.then(stream => {
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var sinea = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    sinea.frequency.value = 440;
    sinea.type = "sine";
    sinea.start();
    sinea.connect(stream);
})
```

no effect. though no exepthion thrown. stream.connect(sinea) - also no way. so what approach should be used here to add some audio filters to the stream data if that's possible? thanks.

Comment: You have two sources here, a microphone and a sine wave. How are you intending for them to affect each other?

Answer (score 0):

Something like (and you'll have to play with this a little)

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
.then(stream => {
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext(); // will work in any modern browser
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var sinea = audioCtx.createOscillator();
    sinea.frequency.value = 440;
    sinea.type = "sine";
    sinea.start();
    source.connect(sinea);
    sinea.connect(audioCtx.destination);
})
```

You attach your device stream to the `AudioContext` by defining it as a `MediaStreamSource`. Then you connect each of your `AudioNode`s together, with a final connection to the context `destination` for that final output.

Then [MDN WebAudio Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) can help you work these things out, and have a lot of examples.

Comment: thanks so much! just tried, now i'm getting this: IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'connect' on 'AudioNode': input index (0) exceeds number of inputs (0), so gonna dig into createChannelMerger() direction ;)